# Total shareholder return calculation

Tags: stock-valuation, rate-of-return

I have investments where I have added to them at various dates over several years and received dividends at various dates. I don't reinvest the dividends in the company but use them to invest across the portfolio. How can I calculate the accurately weighted TSR on a stock - capital and dividend returns at various irregular dates - using excel irr or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't reinvesting in that stock, your return on it is simply the cash dividends plus whatever you are able to get by selling shares. In fact that's the easiest way to calculate it even if you do reinvest in the same stock since:

Converting that into a rate of return requires doing that calculation separately for each day's purchase of shares.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a spread sheet similar to the discounted cash flow calculation in case you have the total return as a accumulated figure as well as the cash flows (buy/sell transactions and dividend payments). Then just need to optimize the calculated interest rate (e.g. trial and error checking of interest rates or with the corresponding mathematical optimization methds), so the discounted cash flow calculation arrives at the total return you got.

Here is a description, I guess they do it similarly:
https://excel-dashboards.com/blogs/blog/excel-tutorial-calculate-return